# need to show image of $f$ contains the unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ be non constant analytic on the closed unit disk,$|f|=1$ if $|z|=1$,we need to show image of $f$ contains the unit disk.

My thoughts:
whenever $|\omega|<1$ if I show that $g(z)=f(z)-\omega$ has a root in $D$ the we are done

On $|z|=1$ $|f(z)-g(z)|=|\omega|<1=|f(z)|$ Hence by Rouches Theorem $f(z)$ has a root in $D$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $f$ does not have a zero. Applying the maximum modulus principle to $1/f(z)$ gives a contradiction ($f$ constant, contradicting the hypothesis), so we find that any analytic function that has modulus $1$ on $|z|=1$ has a zero.

Fix $a$ in the open unit disk. Consider the [Blaschke factor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlaschkeFactor.html) switching $0$ and $a$. Composing $f(z)$ with this factor gives another analytic function with modulus $1$ on the unit circle, so the composition has a zero in the unit disk. But this means $f(z)$ takes on the value $a$ in the unit disk.